# What is the "attack success rate" of an Adversarial Attack?

Tags: adversarial-ml, testing, adversarial-attacks

For a typical adversarial attack, a sample $x_{0}$ is chosen from a training set belonging to class $C_{i}$ and a transformation $A$ is applied such that the adversarial example $x=A(x_{0})$ would be misclassified as $x \in C_{target}$. The adversarial example $x$ could be found iteratively through ${x}={x}_{0}+\eta \cdot \operatorname{sign}\left(\nabla_{{x}} J\left({x}_{0} ; {w}\right)\right)$ for instance.

In [this documentation of TextAttack](https://textattack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/1start/what_is_an_adversarial_attack.html) I read

> Out of those 157, 29 attacks failed, leading to a success rate of 128/157 or 81.5%.

My question is: *how do we chose the starting samples $x_{0}$ (here the 157) to evaluate the success rate of a type of adversarial attack?* Do we chose several target classes? Several initial classes $C_{i}$? How many samples do we chose? From which set (training? validation?)

In the [DeepFool paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.04599.pdf), they'd use the entire test set- but is it standard practice to claim the success rate of a type of attack this way?

Comment: See: https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/14264/17742 and  https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/9767/17742 - the success rate is supposed to be 100%; otherwise it's not an attack, only an attempt.

Comment: The adversarial example is supposed to have a 1/1 success rate, but I can't find a consistent way to chose the samples to evaluate the type of attack throughout the literature